# Is it good practice to use await in a loop?

Tags: javascript, async-await

We can use await in a for loop; however, I am trying to figure out if this is ever a good practice.

I read on MDN: "When an await is encountered in code (either in an async function or in a module), the awaited expression is executed, while all code that depends on the expression's value is paused and pushed into the microtask queue."

I would interpret that as meaning perhaps that //2 and everything below it that depends on the result of //1 would be "pushed into the microtask queue" in each iteration - if my interpretation is correct.

Has an authority on the subject (e.g., MDN) written on if and when this is a good practice?

```
let zeros = new Array(10).fill(0);

(async () => {
    for (let zero of zeros) {
        var r = await new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(r.bind(null, 1), 10)); //1
        console.log(zero);
    }
    console.log(r); //2
})();
```

Comment: Sure, if you want to run some async tasks sequentially, it's probably the easiest and most straightforward approach

Comment: Yes, `await` is specifically intended to permit an asynchronous operation within any of the  control flow structures such as `for` `while` `do` `try` `if` `switch` where you're not ready to `return` from the function yet.

Comment: If steps inside the loop are not dependent, and can be done in parallel, then NO, it is a bad practice, because this way you have each step blocking the next one.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to do.

If for example you must send 3 HTTP requests, it is probably better to run them together like this :

```
await Promise.all([http_get(url_1), http_get(url_2), http_get(url_3)])
```

This way the whole duration of the operation is as long as the longest HTTP GET request, instead of being the sum of the duration of each request.

Comment: The problem with this approach - you'll be wasting valuable processing time, waiting for everything to complete, while you could process data as it resolves.

Comment: @vitaly-t not really, you could have ```http_get()``` channeling responses to another microservice, or saving them. And set a timeout if needed...

Comment: You could, but this is neither shown, not even implied in the answer ;) One can only surmise we are supposed to wait for HTTP requests to resolve.